# ¿Por qué al evaluar una misma cadena con la misma RegExp en JavaScript, a veces valida true y a veces false?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy probando la siguiente expresión regular `/Oh{3,6}/` para que valide las palabras de tipo "Ohhhhh" que tienen entre 3 y 6 h's, usando Visual Studio Code.

Sin embargo no logro entender por qué al evaluar la misma expresión en momentos diferentes en una me la valida `true` y en otra `false`.

¿Alguien sabe por qué sucede eso?

```js
let ohStr = "Ohhh no";
let ohRegex = /Oh{3,6}/g;

let result = ohRegex.test(ohStr);
console.log(ohStr + " " + result);

result = ohRegex.test(ohStr);
console.log(ohStr + " " + result);
```

```
//Al evaluarlo me da esto:
Ohhh no true
Ohhh no false
```

Comment: vaya que es una pregunta interesante +1

Comment: hice algunas pruebas y sin almacenar el resultado la evaluación es la misma

Comment: Pero si lo pones almacenando el resultado te pasa igual o sigues teniendo en true ambas?
Porque justo lo acabo de ejecutar aquí (Que no sabía que se podía XD) y me pasa igual, en uno me da true y en otro false.

Comment: sí, incluso en la consola hay un comportamiento raro, que se almacena como true pero en la consola de firefox prevee que el resultado será false

Answer (score 8):

Cuando utilizas en una Expresión Regular el indicador `g`, el método `test()` hace un seguimiento del último carácter en el que hubo una coincidencia, y la próxima vez que lo ejecutes comenzará por ese carácter.
Este seguimiento se almacena en la propiedad `lastIndex` de la expresión regular.
Una vez que falla el `test` la propiedad se restablece automáticamente a cero, aunque tu puedes hacerlo manualmente.

Para evitar problemas, puedes resetear ese valor a cero después de cada prueba o bien no incluir el indicador `g`. No necesitas el atributo `g` para el método test.

```js
let ohStr = "Ohhh no";
let ohRegex = /Oh{3,6}/g;

console.log(ohRegex.lastIndex)
let result = ohRegex.test(ohStr);
console.log(ohStr + " " + result);

console.log(ohRegex.lastIndex)
resulta = ohRegex.test(ohStr);
console.log(ohStr + " " + resulta);

// Si lo reseteas a cero no va a fallar
result = ohRegex.test(ohStr);
console.log(ohStr + " " + result);

ohRegex.lastIndex = 0
result = ohRegex.test(ohStr);
console.log(ohStr + " " + result);
```

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias, no sabía eso.
Pero si se resuelve el problema =)

Comment: @user250811 igual no necesitas el indicador g para `test`. Puedes eliminarlo y te evitas esos problemas.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.